# Subtraction is giving me positive result C++

Tags: c++, math, calculator, subtraction

```
if (GoalWeight < 0.0) {
    int weeks;
    cout << "How many weeks do you plan to continue this trend?\n";
    cin >> weeks;
    double NewWeight = GoalWeight * weeks;
    double NegBMI = (weight - NewWeight) * 703 / (pow(HeightConverter, 2));
    cout << "If you complete your plan for " << weeks << "weeks you will have a new BMI of: \n" << NegBMI;
}
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Output result:

> What is your current weight?: 180
>
> What is your current height in inches?" 71
>
> Your current BMI is: 25.10(Not part of output, but this is correct)
>
> What is your goal weight change?(lbs) -1.5
>
> How many weeks do you plan to continue this trend?: 6
>
> If you complete your plan for 6 weeks you will have a new BMI of: 26.36

**As you can tell this is wrong**

The calculation for BMI is (weight * 703) /height^2(inches)

What it is doing for negative numbers is:

> 180 + 9(instead of 180 - 9) giving (191 * 703) / 71^2 yielding 26.36

**Instead of:**

> 180 - 9(giving 171 * 703) / 71^2 yielding the correct output of:23.84

I know you're all shaking your heads saying I must be an idiot, and rightfully so, I'm hoping someone can help me with this!

Comment: No, I'm not shaking my head. And you're not an idiot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is your goal weight change?(lbs) -1.5
>
> How many weeks do you plan to continue this trend?: 6

```
6 * ( -1.5 ) == -9
180 - (-9) == 189
```

So you either input goal weight change as positive number or add it, not subtract.

Comment: Wow I am absolutely dense, fixed it and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `newWeight` is resulting to -9 because of your statement `6 * -1.5`.If you want to subtract it just make the `(weight + newWeight)` rather than the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you believe that if you do `(+NewWeight)` the value of `NewWeight`  becomes positive?

this is not the case:

Unary Plus Operator (+): The result of an operation on a numeric type is the value of the operand itself. This operator has been predefined for all numeric types.

As a solution use Reginalds idea and make `(weight + newWeight)` rather than the `-`.

Comment: I tried removing it when I saw it but I guess you saw it beforehand! I was just playing around with what I thought I could do, I compiled it like that and it gave the same answer nonetheless!